# Games with three en passants

Tags: en-passant, famous-games

Games with two en passants in them are are uncommon, and games with three are exceeding rare, and four has never been achieved as far as I know.

I only know of four games with three en passant captures in them, with game #2 arguably being the most famous one because of Tim Krabbe.

1. [A S Segal-K H Podzielny, 1980](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1776547)
2. [Kudrin-R Douven, 1989](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1086879)
3. [G N Gopal-S Zhigalko, 2005](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1369975)
4. [Naiditsch-B Predojevic, 2006](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1411242)

Can more games with three en passants that exist be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a program that reads PGN files that contain thousands of games.
It read 1 317 676 games and found six that fit the criteria.

1. [A Bitalzadeh vs E L'Ami, 2013](https://lichess.org/tb9UWMkP)
2. [I Shahaliyev vs E Ghaem Maghami, 2014](https://lichess.org/kCcCiKMI)
3. [M Petrov vs M Ozdover, 2016](https://lichess.org/uIyYjtfz)
4. [Vi Balint vs G Kjartansson, 2017](https://lichess.org/qI7aYGzD)
5. [J Bonin vs M Paragua, 2019](https://lichess.org/KqY6mdeA)
6. [N Berry vs A Roy, 2019](https://lichess.org/BMCcnPmx)

More could be found. I downloaded all the 1.3 million games from [The Week in Chess](https://theweekinchess.com/twic).